# Use typo3 mail to send mail from external php script

Tags: php, email, typo3

I have ftp access to a server which hosts a web site made with typo3. The web site in typo3 has a contact form somewhere, but I don't have any specifics, for I am not a typo3 developer at all.

I now want to add to that very server a simple service that takes POSTed form data and generates a mail. I have tried a very simple PHP script:

```
<?php
mail("support@mydomain.com", "Bug report", "A new bug report was submitted: " + json_encode($_POST));
echo("<html><head><title>Thank you for your report</title>...
...
?>
```

The rest of the script works (it is executed and `echo` outputs the correct HTML based on the locale), but the mail isn't sent out. I found that the php mail function is unreliable, so I decided to find another way.

- How can I find out how typo3 sends its mails?
- Can I use typo3 code to send mails, and if yes, which scripts do I have to import?
- Could I possibly destroy anything in the typo3 web site by importing typo3 scripts into my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYPO3 uses SwiftMailer to send mails. You can find it in the `contrib` directory (the place of this directory depends on which TYPO3 version you use). TYPO3 only adds a wrapper class to use the mailtransport configuration (mbox, mail(), sendmail, SMTP) which can be set in the Install Tool. 
You can use SwiftMailer in your own code, but you have to use your own configuration.

Comment: Sounds good. Any idea where I can find out the configuration used by typo3, so that I can copy it over? Should be a new typo3 version, the web site has been created by a professional typo3 web agency in May.

Comment: In older versions in `tyoo3conf/localconf.php` and in newer versions in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`.  The latter can be included and returns an array. The settings you need are in the 'MAIL' section. The old version puts settings in `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']`. Depending on which transport is selected one or more of the other settings are used; you'll easily figure out which ones to use.

Comment: `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` may not be the only location where the data is set - it may be set (and usually is in my setups) in the file `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`, which may override settings. I use it (or rather a file included by it) to provide different configurations for development and production setups of the website.